# A switch that activates a horn when power is cut

Tags: current, switches

I am running a wire around the perimeter of my field for approximately 1/4 mile. The wire is not going to be energized but could be. I want to have a horn set up that will blast when the wire is cut. I have an idea how of how to do it but I can't quite figure how to get the horn to blast when the wire to it is cut. There will be power to the horn but it will be switched off until the power is cut. I am sorry if I am not being clear but this is the only way I know how to describe my situation.
To be more clear what I am trying to do is to run an electric wire of very low voltage, maybe 12 volt battery powered, that will trip a switch when cut. When it is cut a switch will trip sounding a horn that requires 12 V dc to blast.

Comment: The wire should make loop. Overwise you need to run pair of wires. Standard solution is resistor between wires at the end of line. Will react also to shorting wires.

Comment: Is it necessary to use battery power or are you thinking 12V for safety reasons?

Answer (score 3):

Use a 12 V relay with the coil energised via the loop.

Wire the bell circuit through the normally closed (NC) contact.

When the loop is broken the relay will release, the NC contract will close and the bell will ring.

Car spares shops will stock what you need. Ask for a relay with a changeover contact and you'll use the NC portion of that.

Comment: This will work but the typical 100 mA current draw of an automotive relay could run down a car battery every couple of weeks.  If it's all to be battery-powered, especially if it's a smaller battery like a gel-cell, a Transistor should be added.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're describing has a name in the building and alarm trade: a *supervised loop*. Basically, a supervised loop uses various techniques to detect if a loop is shorted or open.

More about that here: https://www.douglaskrantz.com/BlogLoopSupervision.html

In your case, you're detecting a wire break. So you want something that continuously monitors the loop wire resistance, like an ohmmeter, and detects a *change* in that resistance which would set off the alarm horn.

Maybe it could be as simple as energizing a relay coil through the loop, then wiring the horn to the 'NC' contacts of the relay. If the loop breaks, the coil is de-energized, which closes the contacts and energizes the horn.

A lower-power solution would 'test' the loop every so often, and if it found it open, sound the horn. That's well within what a microcontroller could do, for very cheap and at low power.